# How to get rid of ogg information in Linux?

Tags: scientific-linux, ogg

How can I get this "something" out of the .ogg file? How can I clear comments/infos like this from the file?

```
$ strings foo.ogg |grep -i SOMETHING
ARTIST=SOMETHING
$
```

OS: Scientific Linux 6.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command `vorbiscomment` to read, modify and delete the metadata on a Ogg Vorbis file. It's part of the `vorbis-tools` package.

#### Installation

```
$ sudo yum install vorbis-tools
```

#### reading

You can use the `-l` switch to list out the tags with their corresponding values like so:

```
$ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg 
title=Antonio Diabelli / Rondino
artist=Various Artists
genre=Classical
date=1998
album=Growing Minds With Music - Classical Music
tracknumber=07
```

#### Modifying

You can modify the tags by writing them out to a file, editing them and then reapplying them back to the .ogg file. This is shown in method #1. You can get fancy and do it as a one liner as in method #2.

*method #1:*

```
$ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg
title=Antonio Diabelli / Rondino
artist=2LiveCrew
genre=Classical
date=1998
album=Growing Minds With Music - Classical Music
tracknumber=07

$ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg > comment.txt
...edit the file...

$ vorbiscomment -w -c     $ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg 
title=Antonio Diabelli / Rondino
artist=2LiveCrew
genre=Classical
date=1998
album=Growing Minds With Music - Classical Music
tracknumber=07comment.txt antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg
```

*method #2:*

```
$ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg  | \
    sed 's/Various Artists/2LiveCrew/' | \
    vorbiscomment -w antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg
```

*after:*

```
$ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg 
title=Antonio Diabelli / Rondino
artist=2LiveCrew
genre=Classical
date=1998
album=Growing Minds With Music - Classical Music
tracknumber=07
```

#### deleting

To delete everything including the artist tag:

```
$ vorbiscomment -w -t "artist=" antonio_diabelli__rondino1.ogg
```

*after:*

```
$ vorbiscomment -l antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg 
artist=
```

There isn't a way to get rid of the last bit. You have to provide `vorbiscomment` at least one tag name with no value, otherwise you'll get the following error:

```
$ echo "" | vorbiscomment -w antonio_diabelli__rondino.ogg 
bad comment: ""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vorbiscomment -w file.ogg  < /dev/null
```

Comment: This is the best for what I needed. Thanks for the idea, it has stood the past of time.